# How to make the animation like when deleting a item in iphones home screen in iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c

I need a help from your side I had items like it in the home screen of the iphone.Also I am having edit button when I click on to the edit button a delete button is shown at the top left corner of every item.The need is when we have a long press in Iphone we will get delete icon at the top left corner and the each item shakes.I want to implement that animation.Can anyone suggest me how to do this animation of shaking?

Anyone's help will be much appreciated.

Thanks to all,
Monish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to set a UIView animation loop that sets the rotate transform to values that tilt it right and left. Should be quite simple. I dont have the code at hand though.